# Resample pandas time series 30 mins for 9:15 as start time

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I am trying to resample OHLC data to 30 mins. The market data starts at at 9:15  and I would like the resampled time to have 9:15-9:45 and so on. But I am able to get the data resampled as 9:00-9:30

[Paste Bin link to 1 min market data](https://pastebin.com/c7UraZdW)

```
pd.DataFrame(download_data).set_index('date'['close'].resample('30T').ohlc()
```

[As you see in the picture the start time is 9:00 and not 9:15...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsGdw.png)

Comment: please dont post image links. Paste the data directly and format as code, helps us to copy paste

Answer (score 3):

There is one more way of doing it, you can use the `base` argument of [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(download_data).set_index('date'['close'].resample('30T', base=15).ohlc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution is add parameter `loffset` in [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

> **loffset** : timedelta
>
> Adjust the resampled time labels

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(download_data)
        .set_index('date')['close']
        .resample('30T', loffset='15min')
        .ohlc())
print (df)

                               open      high      low     close
date                                                            
2018-11-05 09:15:00+05:30  25638.25  25641.85  25589.3  25630.00
2018-11-05 09:45:00+05:30  25622.00  25745.00  25622.0  25714.85
2018-11-05 10:15:00+05:30  25720.05  25740.00  25692.9  25717.00
2018-11-05 10:45:00+05:30  25698.30  25744.75  25667.9  25673.95
2018-11-05 11:15:00+05:30  25680.30  25690.45  25642.9  25655.90
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP wanted. This simply results in mislabelled data. The 30 minute bin in this answer which is now labelled as "2019-11-05 09:15:00+05:30" and should contain data the between 0915 and 0944, actually contains the data for 0900-0929.

Answer (score 1):

@TFA the use of origin='start' may not be that useful esp. if our start time does not fit in that rule of starting from 9:15 am, e.g. if we are trying to convert 1 min data to 15 mins, and we give data from 9:37 am, the 15mins candles will start from 9:37 am, which is not what we need.

The better solution that I could find was to use `origin = <timestamp>`, so something like `origin = datetime.fromisoformat('1970-01-01 09:15:00+05:30')` does the magic.

Overall code:

```
pd.DataFrame(download_data).set_index('date'['close']).resample('30T', origin=datetime.fromisoformat('1970-01-01 09:15:00+05:30')).ohlc()
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the answers provided here work as expected, it must be noted that both <strike>***loffset***</strike> and <strike>***base***</strike> are [deprecated since version 1.1.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). The best and simplest way now is

```
pd.DataFrame(download_data).set_index('date'['close']).resample('30T', origin='start').ohlc()
```

This will set the start time to the first timestamp available in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I will summarize the answers and will add another option for origin.
So yeah, resample method had and argument `base` as a starting position, so it was possible to write it like:

```
data.resample('24h', base=9.5).ohlc()
```

I am using random data just to show how it is done. The base takes floats, so I assumed 9.5 would be 9:30 and it seems to work.
So I am saying **it was possible to use the base argument** because it is deprecated already. Although it still brings nice output:
[image]

As for now, there is a new, nice and clear argument named `origin` in resample method. It takes string as an input, as other answer mentions it also takes keywords like `'start'` or `'end'` but also a string date, so we just put here something something 9:30 and here is what we get:

```
data.resample('24h', origin='2011-12-31 09:30:00').ohlc()
```

And here is the output:

[image]

So just try it with your data.